# wso2 emm - unable to connect via external IP

Tags: wso2, external, connectivity

I have EMM 1.1.0 installed on server with internal IP 10.100.0.1:9443.
Port forwarded by router to external IP 90.90.0.1:23333

Im able to log in locally to https://localhost:9443/emm without a problem.

Cases:

1) After modifying all localhosts in sso-idp-config.xml to internal 10.100.0.1:9443

From internal LAN to //10.100.0.1:9443/emm - able to log in

From external to //90.90.0.1:23333/emm redirected to
//10.100.0.1:9443/samlsso - failed

2) After modifying all localhosts in sso-idp-config.xml to external 90.90.0.1:23333

From internal LAN to //10.100.0.1:9443/emm after log in redirected to //90.90.0.1:23333/emm/acs - failed

From external to //90.90.0.1:23333/emm login?null redirected to
//10.100.0.1:9443/samlsso - failed

What is strange is that iam able to reach //90.90.0.1:23333/carbon from external side in both cases.

Comment: Please say precisely what you mean by "redirect" and "port forwarded by router to external". A screenshot of the router configuration would help to see what you are doing.

Comment: You are now being redirected to SSO Provider. If the redirection fails, please click on the button below. https://10.100.0.1:9443/samlsso and server is unreachable. Unable to get router config right now. Network team provided me with few ports to be able to connect to the server externally.

Comment: Is this programming or server management? It looks to me like the latter. Please remember that StackOverflow is not a generic make-computers-do-things Q&A site; it's specifically for programing.

Comment: It is indeed from server management point of view. I bumped into several related Questions, looks like there is common issue with connectivity to emm behind router/firewall. Looks like unaswered for eternity. Thank you guys for comments..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had the same issue with a public IP, but we have figured it out. It is a configuration issue; we changed the following files and now everything works just fine.

Note that you can also directly change these files at the target directory.

1. modules/distribution/src/repository/conf/api-manager.xml change the following `${carbon.local.ip}` with your public IP

`<ServerURL>https://${carbon.local.ip}:${mgt.transport.https.port}/services/</ServerURL>`

`<GatewayEndpoint>http://${carbon.local.ip}:${http.nio.port},https://${carbon.local.ip}:${https.nio.port}</GatewayEndpoint>`

2. /modules/distribution/src/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml add the following parameter.

   `<parameter name="bind-address" locked="false">YOUR_PUBLIC_IP</parameter>`
3. /modules/distribution/src/repository/conf/carbon.xml change the following definitions with your public IP.

   HostName and MgtHostName
4. /modules/distribution/src/repository/conf/identity.xml and /modules/distribution/src/repository/conf/sso-idp-config.xml replace the localhost with the public IP.

Comment: Thank you flock for your help, much appreciate it. I just changed all to my local IP as suggested, changed https port to my public one also. Now i can see that SSO provider redirection is with my local ip, but with internal port 9443. Still unreachable at https://local_ip:9443/samlsso. Same with /publisher and if i try to sign in /store. :(

Comment: Hello Lukas, please make sure that, you have changed all the localhost occurrences with your Public IP especially at the identity.xml and sso-idp-config.xml. And alos, just in case please add to your /etc/hosts file public_ip localhost definition. And one more suggestion, sometimes there would be two different config files, such as there are two identity.xml files located under the target folder, with the same name, at the target. Also make sure they have changed too.

Comment: Well still no luck:( all meaningfull localhost entries changed to public ip, there is only one occurence of each config file under ../repository/conf. I'm still confused how emm works with forwarded port and redirection. Thanks you anyway flock for your help.

Comment: There might be more than one XML files under the same name, and unfortunately it is hard to figure out which one is active. Search the name of the configuration file, under the target folder, you can see that there are more than one files. May be you can try step by step, first change the IP address, Once make sure that everything is fine then, change the port.

Comment: Internal-external IP redirection working as intended after localhost modification. But redirection from publicIP:publicPort/emm to publicIP:privatePort/samlsso is still wrong. Let me know if somebody manage to locate proper file for modification. Thank you:)