# Wso2-emm and SAML SSO configuration

Tags: single-sign-on, wso2, wso2-iot

I am new in WSO2 and I have some problem with emm and sso login.

I cloned the w**so2 emm project** from github.

I used maven clean install to generate wso2emm-1.1.0 zip (under product-emm-master\modules\distribution\target)

When I start **wso2server.bat**, I can only acces to **carbon** and **store**, but when I access to emm I had a redirection to https://localhost:9443/sso/ with this

> error 500: Something has gone wrong (Problem in
>   (/emm/modules/sso.js#23)).

Even when I login within the store app I had a redirection to this URL

> https://192.168.56.1:9443/admin/samlsso

Do I need some configuration in the code source to configure SAML SSO ? I need to know if emm needs some pre-configuration steps ?

Thanks

Comment: Hello, did you check the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30291923/wso2-emm-unable-to-connect-via-external-ip/30303416#30303416 question?

Comment: Hello, yes but I still have the same promblem !! I can't configure sso SAML connection and  I can't access to https://localhost:9443/emm/ !! Any help please

Answer (score 1):

Do you have VmWare installed? Because it confuses the IP configuration of the computer by utilizing the networking bridges.

I would suggest you that first check your ip configuration via,

```
ifconfig
```

And from the network preferences delete the bridged connection if exists. After that restart the, server and try again.

Comment: Thank you flock.dux, I chekout my network preferences and I didn't find any bridged. I think my problem is that I messed up some configuration in the code source of emm :(.

Answer (score 0):

Can I see the logs? You can activate debug logs from going into WSO2_SERVER_HOME/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/emm and open the file jaggery.conf and go to the bottom to find "logLevel" property and change it to "logLevel": "debug". Save the file and try the above scenario. While you are doing this, open your terminal to check the logs and please post a copy of the exception you are getting here. You can also get the recent logs by going into WSO2_SERVER_HOME/repository/logs/wso2carbon.log.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Kasun, this is the error when I type https://172.16.0.81:9443/emm/login?null, I can't access to sso to login :
ERROR {org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager} - TypeError: Impossible de trouver la fonction address dans lobjet {1}. (/emm/modules/sso.js#23) {org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager} org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: TypeError: Impossible de trouver la fonction address dans lobjet {1}. (/emm/modules/sso.js#23) 
.......
I log in sso.js file and I find that "sso.transport" return null 
sso.address = carbon.server.address(sso.transport);

Comment: Did you try creating a tenant? Or is this when you try using the default credentials, "admin", "admin"?

Comment: No, I used the default credentails "admin", "admin". I note that I compiled WSO2 in Ubuntu OS and it is worked well. The problem figure out only when I compiled it in Windows OS. Moreover, I tried to change sso configuration in \repository\conf\security\application-authenticators.xml <Status value="10" loginPage="/sso/login" /> by <Status value="10" loginPage="https://localhost:9443/authenticationendpoint/login.do" /> and it is worked and I can access to emm url with the default credentials admin admin