# Build WSO2 EMM On windows 7 OS

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I encountered the same problem described on the following question:
[Wso2-emm and SAML SSO configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30707998/wso2-emm-and-saml-sso-configuration)

But When I Build the WSo2 EMM Project(https://github.com/wso2/product-emm) with the same maven version on Linux OS and I excute the server on the two OS Windows and Linux, the problem does not arise.

Is it necessary to Build WSO2 EMM project on Linux OS or are there specific configurations to add on windows OS?

Answer (score 0):

It will support in Windows platform as well. I have personally tested this in Windows 7 and worked without any issue.