# Published Apps do not show up in WSO2 Default Enterprise Store

Tags: android, wso2, wso2-iot

Using WSO2 EMM V2.0.0, as and admin, I added an android APK to the enterprise app store and published it. When I went to the store there is a message "We couldn't find anything for you". I click sign in and the login page is shown. I sign in as admin, the screen jumps to a page that says "No Privileges to login".  Login works for EMM, and for the publisher.I added all privileges to the admin but still do not have privileges to login. I still get no apps in the app store and the store login still goes to an error page with No privileges to login.
How do I get login to work for the store?
How do I get apps to show up in the store?

Comment: generally it takes couple of hours to be visible in Google Play Store. Be patient !

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear, I am referring to WSO2's enterprise store, not the play store. I thought the tags were sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

According to Play store, the usually takes 24 hours to appear in the search.

> If your app is not appearing for 24 hours, please select one of the options below:
>
> ...

Reference: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/troubleshooter/3055329?hl=en

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear, I am referring to WSO2's enterprise store, not the play store. I thought the tags were sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and only managed to resolve it by unzipping a fresh copy of the EMM with a brand new database. Nothing else I tried worked.

Comment: The setup instructions are insufficient for EMM 2.0.  What files did you change to remove the localhost setting and replace with the server's hostname? what additional files did you change for reasons other than removing the localhost settings?

Comment: In order to stop it from redirecting to LocalHost for the Store and Publisher, I had to go by [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30303416/4561759) answer . I also had to modify the **IdentityProviderUrl**, **providerUrl**, and **ServerUrl** in the app-manager.xml file under [EMM_HOME]/respository/conf to have the server's IP address instead of LocalHost.

Comment: You have not changed store configurations properly. Please look into wso2 EMM store Jaggery app config.json file.

Comment: I believe Dilshan is referring to [EMM_HOME]\repository\deployment\server\jaggeryapps\emm\config\config.json.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! Turns out, at least for my issue, it was caused by me changing the admin account's password. I did this via the EMM Dashboard.

Simply changing the password back to 'admin' resolved the issue. Obviously this is a bug, so an appropriate bug report has been filed with WSo2.

Answer (score 0):

By default if you logged in as username and password as admin ,admin respectively, and publish the app, it will by default goes to the carbon.super tenant.So you can view that app in that tenant.If you want to add apps on other tenants then you have to login from the tenants admin credentials.